# using "order by" on inner join MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

hello master around the world, im here again with a problem :D

now i wanna ask something simple for you but really I'm new on programming and sql, so need more learn.

ok, lets to the problem. I have some sql query like this

```
SELECT
eu_product.*,
eu_shop_display.display_name as dname,
eu_product_img.image_url as img
FROM eu_product
INNER JOIN eu_product_img on eu_product_img.product_id = eu_product.product_id
INNER JOIN eu_shop_display on eu_shop_display.display_id = eu_product.product_display
where eu_product.publish=1
and eu_product.shop_id=1
and eu_product.product_display IN (select display_id from eu_shop_display where parent_id=1) 
or eu_product.product_display = 1
GROUP BY eu_product.product_id 
ORDER BY eu_product.product_id DESC  LIMIT 0, 10
```

The problem is in

> INNER JOIN eu_product_img on
>   eu_product_img.product_id =
>   eu_product.product_id

the table seen like this

[image]

I need to using Order ASC on field "listing".

is SQL query can use two order by, or can adding order by in inner join ? i try adding

```
ORDER BY eu_product.product_id DESC, eu_product_img.listing ASC
```

but its not working :(

maybe someone can explain how its work.

---

**UPDATE**

> .< maybe i'll make simple query

this product table

[image]

this product_img table

[image]

and this a result

[image]

but the " eu_product_img.listing ASC " not run correctly :(

**i need the listing on product_id 1 is 1 not 4**

see the table product_img

i need run the product_img.listing order ASC first before joined it.

the correct query is like this

```
SELECT eu_product.product_id, 
(select img.listing from eu_product_img as img where img.product_id = eu_product.product_id order by img.listing ASC limit 1 ) as listing 
    FROM eu_product 
    where eu_product.shop_id=1 
    or eu_product.product_display = 2 
    GROUP BY eu_product.product_id 
    ORDER BY eu_product.product_id DESC  LIMIT 0, 20
```

so it cannot using inner join ?

thanks before.

Regard,
Stecy

Comment: What do you want to sort on? `product_id` and `listing`? `ORDER BY eu_product.product_id DESC, eu_product_img.listing ASC` should work. Is the MySQL ordering being respected in whatever output function you're putting it?

Comment: If you paste the desired output here, You might get better response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working. You see from the screenshot that they are first ordered by product_id and then by listing. If you just want to order by listing, then do `ORDER BY eu_product_img.listing ASC`. If you want to order by listing then product, reverse your order by statements.

Order by accepts multiple statements, but your results will be ordered in the order you specify the order statements ;) So, if listing is first, results are ordered by listing first, etc.

Comment: ORDER BY **eu_product.product_id** DESC, **eu_product_img.listing** ASC its different table :(

Comment: i agree with this comment, but the ordering does no appear correctly in the OP output.

Comment: @Stecy, that doesnt matter... you can order by any column in any of the tables included in your query. That is basic SQL.

Comment: so when product_id = 1, listing should = 1? Your inner join defines that relationship and so long as I am understanding the context around your column names, you have that right.

Comment: yeah, the correct query like **SELECT** eu_product.product_id, 
(select img.listing from eu_product_img as img where img.product_id = eu_product.product_id order by img.listing ASC limit 1 ) as listing from **... ** so it cannot using inner join @brad ???

Comment: No, it should use an INNER JOIN. What I am saying is that the relationship between product_id and listing is defined by your INNER JOIN. Order would not matter here. What should listing be when product_id = 7?

Comment: its same should be 0 or 1, because the field listing just number from 0 to 4.. if i run SELECT eu_product.product_id, 
(select img.listing from eu_product_img as img where img.product_id = eu_product.product_id order by img.listing ASC limit 1 ) as listing 
    FROM eu_product 
    where eu_product.shop_id=1 
    or eu_product.product_display = 2 
    GROUP BY eu_product.product_id 
    ORDER BY eu_product.product_id DESC  LIMIT 0, 20
the result is correct what i need